# I have "unresolved externals"

Tags: unresolved-external

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    const int STUDENTS = 100;

    struct studentType
    {
        string fname;
        string lname;
        int test1;
        int test2;
        int test3;
        int test4;
        double average;
        char grade;
    };

    void initRecords(studentType students[]);
    int readData(studentType students[]);
    double getStudentAverageGrade(studentType aStudent);
    char getGrade(double average);
    void sortRecords(studentType students[], int totalStudents);
    void swapRecords(studentType& aStudent, studentType& bStudent);
    void writeRecords(studentType students[], int totalStudents);
    void drawLine(ofstream& fout, char ch, int width);
    void checkRecords(studentType students[], int totalStudents);
    int findMax(int, int);
    int findMin(int, int);

    int main()
    {
        int totalStudents = 0;
        studentType students[STUDENTS];
        initRecords(students);
        totalStudents = readData(students);
        checkRecords(students, totalStudents);
        sortRecords(students, totalStudents);
        cout << endl << "after sorting..." << endl;
        checkRecords(students, totalStudents);
        writeRecords(students, totalStudents);
        cout << "Done!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    void initRecords(studentType students[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++)
        {
            students[i].fname = "AA";
            students[i].lname = "ZZ";
            students[i].grade = 'F';
            students[i].test1 = 0;
            students[i].test2 = 0;
            students[i].test3 = 0;
            students[i].test4 = 0;
            students[i].average = 0.0;
        }
    }

    int readData(studentType students[])
    {
        ifstream fin;
        string fileName;
        int i;
        cout << "Enter filename: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        fin.open(fileName);
        if (!fin)
        {
            cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
            exit (0);
        }
        i = 0;
        while (fin && i < STUDENTS)
        {
            fin >> students[i].fname >> students[i].lname >> students[i].test1 >> students[i].test2 >> students[i].test3 >> students[i].test4;

            if (!fin)
                break;

            students[i].average = getStudentAverageGrade(students[i]);
            students[i].grade = getGrade(students[i].average);
            i += 1;
        }
        fin.close();
        return i;
    }

    void checkRecords(studentType students[], int totalStudents)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++)
        {
            cout << students[i].fname << " " << students[i].lname << " " << students[i].test1 << " " << students[i].test2 << " " << students[i].test3 << " " << students[i].test4 << " " << students[i].average << " " << students[i].grade << endl;

        }
    }
```

I have had this error a few times with multiple programs, it kind of seems to come and go, I do not fully understand the unresolved external error, and I have searched before for help with it, and can not seem to find any legitimate advice, I am not asking anyone to do my homework, I just would like someone to point out what is causing this error, and possible ways to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

UPDATE: error message Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl getStudentAverageGrade(struct studentType)" (?getStudentAverageGrade@@YANUstudentType@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl readData(struct studentType * const)" (?readData@@YAHQAUstudentType@@@Z)   c:\Users\cpsalazar\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Assignment7.cpp\Assignment7.cpp\Assignment7.obj    Assignment7.cpp

There are 3 more for sortRecords, writeRecords, and getGrade.

Comment: Search this site for `unresolved external`. Every one of the hundreds of previous posts tell you what causes these errors and how to fix them. Use those posts to track down the problem and fix it. We can't repeat the same answer for every single differently named unresolved external anyone ever encounters, or we'd have no time to answer other questions here.

Comment: Show the actual error message. In the case of the code you show, there are declarations for `sortRecords()` and `writeRecords()` but no implementation for those functions. The linker is complaining that these references are "external" (because they're not in this module) and "unresolved" (because the linker can't find them anywhere).

Comment: Thank you, I think I can figure it out.